# How to get date time from date in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a table having column `order date` like this `2019-06-01`.

But I need to show date and time also like this 2019-06-01 00:00:00.000

Please suggest

Comment: What is the data type of the column?

Comment: Sounds like you just need to change the display formation in your **presentation layer** to `yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.sss` (might be wrong symbol for split seconds) from `yyyy-MM-dd`.

Comment: Hey Forpas Date

Comment: `select convert(datetime,'2019-06-01')` ?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do a simple `CAST()` assuming your type is a date like you mentioned. It is stored as a date, but you want it to be presented as a datetime.

```
SELECT CAST(your_col AS DATETIME) AS your_col
FROM your_table
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do it.  This should be pretty straight forward though:

```
DECLARE @TEST DATE
SET @TEST = '2019-06-01'
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, @TEST)
```

yields:

`2019-06-01 00:00:00.000`

Really doing what you are looking for, making your datatype of `DATE` into `DATETIME`

However as suggested in the comments depending on how this data is used you might just want to append stuff to it on the presentation layer.  Really up to you!  Good luck. :)